# Launching the default music player

Tags: android, android-intent, android-music-player

I'm trying to launch the music player so it will launch and immediately start playing the first song. im using an Intent but it just doesn't work...it says "no activity found to handle intent".

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       //"songsList" is an array with paths of all the songs in the sdcard
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(songsList.get(0));
    String type = "audio/mp3";
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Try media type `audio/*` - it's what I use and it works fine. Maybe nothing has registered `audio/mp3` as a specific mime-type.

Comment: What is the `Uri` value?

Comment: path of the first song

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER)?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(intent);
```

Note that this is deprecated from API 15, FROM API upwards you can use [`android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC).

Comment: this one's really weird it only launches a music player called "playerpro" so i've deleted playerpro from my phone and then it just crashed

Comment: Do you have any other music players installed?

Comment: do i need to add anything else to my app for launching the music player...?

Comment: well actually now i can choose an app to use from a list but i cant see all of my music players

Comment: Hmm.. that's really strange.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER"); is working for me on ANdroid 4.2.2 on Nexus 4

Answer (score 2):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(AUDIO_PATH);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.music");          
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

To launch default music player, please try with below code.

```
try {
    Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Exception for launching music player "+e);
}
```

Comment: That is the correct way. As of this date, all other suggested methods are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

ok so i find this code that works

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();  
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
                File file = new File(songsList.get(0));  
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
                startActivity(intent);
```

but the thing is that lets say that the user hits the back button and then hits the button of the music player,  it restarts the player and starts playing the first song again...
so how do i just launch the music player without anything else...?