# How do i launch the music player

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How am i suppose to use this

```
android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC
```

to launch the music player?
it doesn't work if i call makeMainSelectorActivity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();  
 intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(intent.ACTION_MAIN, 
 "android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC");
  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution might help someone looking to launch default Music Player:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15){        
    Intent intent=Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
    Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);//Min SDK 15
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");//Min SDK 8
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Amir, this thread does not relate to media streaming at all, not sure why you had to down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Used below code :

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "1");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);   
startActivity(it);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(intent);
```

Ans also prefer url :

[Launching the default music player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792018/launching-the-default-music-player)

Comment: i've found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532207/open-music-player-on-galaxy-s3?rq=1 a code that opens the music player by using it's package name but the thing is that i want the user to choose which music player to open