# Creating and intent using makeMainActivity

Tags: android

I am researching on different possibilities of creating an intent in android and I came across **makeMainActivity**, **makeMainSelectorActivity** and **makeRestartActivityTask**. Can any one tell me how to create an intent with them.

Comment: Look out the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html

Comment: are you looking for [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798251/how-do-i-launch-the-music-player)